# Why must I create objects on a page above an array containing them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've worked out the "how" of this, so it's not urgent, but the "why" is bugging me!

I am creating a bank of about 500 test items for making mock practice tests for the Thai national English test (ONET). Each item is declared as an object containing html, answer key etc.

Then all items are placed into an array, which is shuffled, and the first *n* items become the mock test.

Up until now, I've used a separate js file to create the question objects, but the code creating the **array** of questions remained on my main js file. But, today I realised that if I shifted this array declaration to my secondary page, then as I added items, I would only need to update the secondary page on the computers that run this app. (Because of poor Internet connections, this is mostly run as a stand-alone off-line electron app.)

So I replaced the array declaration from my main page with one at the **top** of my secondary js page as follows:

```
var onet_full_array = new Array(cloze005, pass002, pass007, single001,
single002, single003, single004, single005); //abbreviated
```

However, when I tried to access that array, the elements showed as undefined. After trying several other things, I finally tried putting the array declaration at the **bottom** of the page, after the object declarations and it worked.

What's bugging me is why this should be necessary. It seems we constantly refer to variables, functions and so forth that may appear anywhere on the page, provided the scope is correct. I would have thought that the browser would read the entire page before deciding that it couldn't find my objects. After all, when my array declaration was on a different page, it didn't complain.

What am I missing?

**Edit:** Just for clarity, what I was missing, as stated in the comments, was that my original array declaration was inside a function that was not run during set-up. So by the time that function was run, the objects **had** been declared.

Comment: define array as `var onet_full_array = [cloze005, pass002, pass007, single001,
single002, single003, single004, single005];`

Comment: You've put a lot of effort into vaguely describing what your code kind of looks like.  Why not show *actual code* which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I would need to see more code to determine precisely why its doing this but my first guess just from your description is depending how this secondary JS file was included it was initializing that array with undefined objects because those objects had not been initialized yet.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The problem about showing more code was which parts of the code to show exactly. In fact, as mentioned in my response to deceze, if I had shown that my array declaration had originally been inside a function, it would probably have made my problem obvious - perhaps even to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Array(cloze005, pass002, ..)
```

This is creating a new array and is trying to place **the value** of `cloze005` into it. If `cloze005` is not yet defined/does not yet have a value assigned, then no value can be placed in the array. You cannot assign values to the variable *after* you have placed it in an array and expect the value to be retroactively placed in the array as well. Code doesn't execute in random order and anything goes at any time.

Comment: Thanks for this - it pointed me in the right direction. What confused me was why my array declaration seemed to work when it was in the other file. Finally I realised - the declaration was inside a function that wasn't run during set-up. So, by the time it created the array, the objects **had** already been created in the second file.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to expect variables to act like pointers. Your array contains values, not references.  Whatever the value at the time the array was created is the value that remains.

I think a demo helps to clarify more than just words.  Consider the following code.  Before you click <kbd>► Run code snippet</kbd>, think about what you expect to be logged.

```js
var a = [x];
var x = 0;
var b = [x];
x = 1;
var c = [x];

log(a);
log(b);
log(c);

function log(val) { document.write("<pre>[ " + val[0] + " ]</pre>"); }
```

Based on your question, it seems like you expected to see:

```
[ 1 ]

[ 1 ]

[ 1 ]
```

You don't see this because, rather than containing a pointer-like reference to `x`, the arrays are created by evaluating the value of `x` and storing that value.

Comment: Thanks for this - it also helped steer me in the right direction. I guess part of my confusion was/is not understanding when js is modal, and when it is amodal. After this, I certainly have a better grip on modal behaviour. Would I be right in saying that js is amodal mostly when processing function calls?